# Are there alternative payment methods for donations?

Tags: donation

PayPal won't accept the card I have, and I wanted to say "thank you" for all the work on Ubuntu with, well, some cash.  How else can I pay?

Comment: I would suggest asking your bank if PayPal doesn't accept your card. AFAIK you need to register the card **first** with PayPal then you can use it.

Comment: At least here in the USA, PayPal Accounts can be linked directly to a checking account - without the need for any "card". You do have to go through a few steps to verify the account and your ownership of it for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

If PayPal does not accept your card - maybe your country is not supported or any other reason - I do not believe you can donate any other way. At least not that I know of.

There is an alternative though.

You can visit the Canonical shop and buy something at http://shop.ubuntu.com

There is no need to use PayPal at the shop for your purchases.

Also, the link to the shop is available at the top of this website, and any other Ubuntu affiliated website.